# Netbook slows to a halt quite gradually

Tags: windows-7, performance

### Issue:

Machine boots at normal speed, but slows down and grinds to a halt within about half an hour.

---

### Observations:

First occurred this morning (about twelve hours ago)

It hasn't had a physical impact in the last couple of days, nor has anything new been installed (confirmed from the 'Installed On' columns in Installed Updates & Programs and Features)

Windows Event Log shows some HP services timing out and giving up

Normal windows processes are strangling the processor by CPU time and %

Nothing is consuming much RAM

Disk IO is minimal

---

### Already Checked:

Malwarebytes (AV): nothing found

AdwCleaner (AV): nothing terminal

AVG Free (AV): nothing terminal

chkdsk (HDD): no errors

Windows Memory Diagnostic Tool (RAM): no errors

Googled and trawled SuperUser's uptime-associated performance questions.

---

### Specs:

```
OS: Win 7 Starter (6.1) 32bit SP1

Device: HP Mini 110-3500

Processor: Intel Atom N550

RAM: 2GB
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temperature-initiated CPU throttling was the cause of this behaviour.

I placed a column heater directly under my desk before breakfast, as it's the middle of winter in Tasmania, and moving the heater back a little has totally resolved this issue.